Function for which the integral $I[y]=\int_{0}^{\infty}(y^2 + (y')^2 + (y' + y'')^2)dx$ is stationary
Show that the only function $y(x)$ with $y(0)=1, y'(0)=2$ and $y(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ for which the integral $$I[y]=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}(y^2 + (y')^2 + (y' + y'')^2)dx$$ is stationary is $$y(x) = (3x+1)e^{-x}$$
As our integrand, $f$, is a function of $y,y', y''$, the E-L equation is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y''} = 0$$ and since $f$ is not a function of $x$, we have the first integral $$f - y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} - y'' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y''} = c$$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$. These equations then become $$y -  2y'' + y^{(4)} = 0$$ and $$y^2 - 2(y')^2 - 2y'y'' - (y'')^2 = c$$ However, I can see no way in how to find $y$ from these two equations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You are actually half-way there. Watch what happens with the equation $y-2y''+y^{(4)}=0$ when you seek for the solution of the form $y=exp(\lambda x)$.

Solving $y -  2y'' + y^{(4)} = 0$ we have
$$
y(x) = c_1 e^{-x}+c_2 e^{-x} x+c_3 e^x+c_4 e^x x
$$
and as $y(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ we need $c_3=c_4 = 0$ then
$$
y(x) = e^{-x}(c_1+c_2 x)
$$
subjected to $y(0) = 1, y'(0)= 2$

I guess I would need to elaborate on my comment, since it might be slightly vague.
So, let's start off with the equation $$y-2y''+y^{(4)}=0$$ and look for the solution in the following form: $y=e^{\lambda x}$. Plugging that into the ODE, one obtains:
$$
e^{\lambda x} - 2 \cdot \lambda^{2} e^{\lambda x} + \lambda^{4} e^{\lambda x} = 0.
$$
Since $e^{\lambda x}$ is positive, we may divide both sides of the equation by that factor
$$
1-2\lambda^{2}+\lambda^{4} = (1-\lambda^{2})^{2}
$$
to acquire $\lambda=\pm1$, both with the algebraic multiplicity equal to two. If you are familiar with the ODE theory, the multiplicity implies that the solution will have to contain non-trivial exponents, a.k.a. associated exponents, the association being a polynomial $P_m(x)$, where $m$ is one less the multiplicity of the root.
So, all facts combined, we should seek the general solution in the form:
$$
y = c_{1}e^{x} + c_{2}xe^{x} + c_{3}e^{-x} + c_{4}xe^{-x}
$$
Notice, however, that the condition requires $y$ to vanish at infinity. Hence, for arbitrary $c_1$ and $c_2$ the solution should tend to zero. This is achievable if and only if $c_1=c_2=0$, reducing the form of the solution to $$y = c_{3}e^{-x} + c_{4}xe^{-x} = (c_{3} + c_{4}x)e^{-x}.$$
The rest is fairly simple:

using the condition $y(0)=1$, one gets $c_3=1$.
the first derivative of the solution is:
$$
y'=(1+c_4x)e^{-x}=e^{-x}(c_4-1-c_4x).
$$
Evaluation at zero gives $y'(0)=2=c_4-1$, from where $c_4=3$.

Finally, $y(x)=(1+3x)e^{-x}$.
